# Adding text files to binaries with objcopy, but objcopy complains about architecture

Tags: embedded-resource, objcopy

I've read about [embedding text files](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967) (or any other resource for that matter) into binaries, and I'm doing it like so:

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm --binary-architecture arm myfile.txt myfile.txt.o
```

However, unlike in the tutorial, I get the following response:

```
ld: unknown architecture of input file `myfile.txt' is incompatible with arm output
```

The example uses i386 but this doesn't seem to be the issue either as I can't do it that way either.

Is there a way I can force objcopy to ignore the fact it's a text file and not a valid compatible binary so it just copies it byte-for-byte into my program?

Answer (score 0):

For data only object file (no code), you can skip `binary-architecture` option.

So the following should work

`objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm myfile.txt myfile.txt.o` to generate object file.